# Assigning 20 tennis players to 14 games

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

$20$ tennis players are scheduled to play exactly $14$ two-person games among themselves, with each player playing at least one game. Prove there must be a set of $6$ games with $12$ distinct players.

To set it up, I let $G$ be a graph on $20$ vertices (players) and $14$ edges (games). Two vertices are adjacent if and only if they play each other in a game. Note that since each player plays a game, each vertex has degree at least $1$.

Using $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{20} deg(v_i) = 28} $, we can show that at least $12$ vertices have degree $1$. Also, we can show that the largest degree any vertex can have is $8$.

I believe we should show there is a matching of size $6$ on $G$.

Is this a good method? If so, any suggestion on how to show this would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You already know that all $20$ vertices have at-least degree $1$ since each player plays a game. You are assigning $28$ degrees to $20$ vertices with each vertex having atleast $1$ degree. So the maximum degree any vertex can have is $9$, when every other vertex has degree $1$.

Comment: Well, you cannot have 19 vertices of degree 1. So the larges degree is 8, with one having degree 2, and then the last 18 vertices having degree 1.

Comment: Why not? Consider a graph in which one vertex is adjacent to $9$ other vertices of degree $1$.  Form pairs from the remaining $10$ vertices and connect each pair.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have atmost $5$ games with distinct players. Let the set of these distinct players be $S$. Then the remaining $10$ players can't play any game among themselves because if they did, you would have $6$ games with distinct players. Thus each of these $10$ players must play a game with someone from $S$. This will make $5+10=15$ games which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! Was my interpretation of the situation as a graph completely unnecessary?

Comment: @J-Q-McNeedHelpson No! This is one way to solve it without Graph Theory. A graph theory solution will be an interesting way to observe how what I have said translates in the context of graphs. I will try to work one up.

Answer (score 1):

Borrow your graph setting:

> let G be a graph on 20 vertices (players) and 14 edges (games). Two vertices are adjacent if and only if they play each other in a game.
> Note that since each player plays a game, each vertex has degree at
> least 1.

Suppose $G$ has $k$ components.

For any graph, we have $|E(G)|\ge |V(G)|-k $. This gives $k\ge |V(G)|-|E(G)|=6$. i.e. $G$ has at least 6 components. Note every component has at least one edge as $\delta(G)\ge1$.

By picking one edge from every component, we can always find 6 edges and the 12 distinct vertices.